# How I make QuerySelectorAll() to select all html tags and I make changes by accessing index of html tag

Tags: javascript, html

For Example : I have the following code

```
    <div class="set">
    <button class =  "w drum"> w  </button>
    <button class =  "a drum"> a  </button>
    <button class =  "s drum"> s  </button>
    <button class =  "d drum"> d  </button>
    <button class =  "j drum"> j  </button>
    <button class =  "k drum"> k  </button>
    <button class =  "l drum"> l  </button>
  </div>
```

Now I want to select all button tags and perform .addEventListener function in all buttons .I implement it by for loop. But I wanna ask is there any way that we can implement it through the following way...

```
  document.querySelectorAll("button")[0,1,2,3,4,5,6].addEventListener("click",pressButton);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to add click listener on "drum" class

Comment: So, same event listener for all of them'

Comment: yes,same event listener on all rather than binding every element since it serves this use case

Answer (score 3):

You can add an `addEventListener` function to the `prototype` of [NodeList](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp) and call that. Here you go:

```js
NodeList.prototype.addEventListener = function(indexes, listener, eventName) {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
        if (indexes.indexOf(index) >= 0) this[index].addEventListener(eventName, listener);
    }
};
function pressButton() {console.log(this.innerText);}
document.querySelectorAll("button").addEventListener([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], pressButton, "click");
```

```html
<div class="set">
<button class =  "w drum"> w  </button>
<button class =  "a drum"> a  </button>
<button class =  "s drum"> s  </button>
<button class =  "d drum"> d  </button>
<button class =  "j drum"> j  </button>
<button class =  "k drum"> k  </button>
<button class =  "l drum"> l  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do something like this incase you don't want to use the simple for loop

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(value=>
value.addEventListener("click",e=>console.log(e.target.innerText)))
```

```html
<div class="set">
  <button class =  "w drum"> w  </button>
  <button class =  "a drum"> a  </button>
  <button class =  "s drum"> s  </button>
  <button class =  "d drum"> d  </button>
  <button class =  "j drum"> j  </button>
  <button class =  "k drum"> k  </button>
  <button class =  "l drum"> l  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can remove the curly braces for implicit return

Comment: What if he wants to create event listeners to only a subset of the items?

Comment: @LajosArpad maybe using switch case

Comment: That would complicate the syntax rather then simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the right approach.
You have to loop through each element and add the event listener like below,

```js
const button = document.querySelectorAll("button");

const pressButton = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.innerText);
}

for (const btn of button) {
 btn.addEventListener("click", pressButton);
}
```

```html
<div class="set">
<button class =  "w drum"> w  </button>
<button class =  "a drum"> a  </button>
<button class =  "s drum"> s  </button>
<button class =  "d drum"> d  </button>
<button class =  "j drum"> j  </button>
<button class =  "k drum"> k  </button>
<button class =  "l drum"> l  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't `of` only work for arrays while `querySelectorAll` returns an **array-like** object

Comment: The asker already knows that, but would like to simplify the syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use **event delegation**, using `e.target` in the event handler. You only need to add the event listener to the parent, and then you iterate over an array of class names, performing a block of code each time.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. But I would prefer to add an id to the div instead of class as multiple elements can have the same class name

```
document.querySelectorAll('.set')[0].addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if(event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
     // do your stuff
     console.log("clicked a button");
  }
})
```

Comment: What if the event needs to be different for each button?

Comment: then you can add a switch case for the "innerText" of "className" of the button and put code individually for each case or each type of button

Comment: The goal of the question was to simplify the syntax. Your answer moves towards complication instead. Check out my answer, which simplifies the syntax indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This function takes all button elements that are in the DIV element with class `.set` and adds them EventListener.

In the `function clickMe`, you can add the action you want to happen when a button is clicked.

I hope I have been helpful

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('set')[0];
var butt = x.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < butt.length; i++) {
    butt[i].addEventListener("click", clickMe);
}

function clickMe() {
    var res = this.innerText
    console.log(res);
}
```

```html
<div class="set">
    <button class =  "w drum"> w  </button>
    <button class =  "a drum"> a  </button>
    <button class =  "s drum"> s  </button>
    <button class =  "d drum"> d  </button>
    <button class =  "j drum"> j  </button>
    <button class =  "k drum"> k  </button>
    <button class =  "l drum"> l  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but the asker wanted to simplify the syntax.